# Registro default caso não tenha nenhum outro - mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, phpmyadmin, migrations

É possível programar o banco para que exista um registro default caso não exista outro na tabela? tornando a tabela impossível de estar vazia.

então se tem outros registro ele ignora o default, caso não tenha nenhum ele use o default.

é possível?

Estou implementando permissões de acesso em um sistema que já tem muitos usuários e grande parte dos usuários não tem permissão registrada então causa problema na hora de verificar permissões e etc.. então gostaria de montar um registro que sempre existisse por padrão de configuração.

Comment: Provavelmente seria o caso de fazer isso na aplicação. IF tem registro no db, $permissoes = campo do db, else $permissoes = usuario padrão. A vantagem disso é que se forem várias permissoes diferentes, vc grava apenas as diferentes do padrão pra cada usuário.

Comment: Sim.. o maior problema é que essas permissões estão atreladas a planos diferentes então obrigatoriamente eu preciso ter planos e permissões básicas cadastradas @Bacco

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha acho que a melhor opção é tu tentar corrigir o método que valida as permissões, acho muita gambiarra criar um registro default no banco.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar uma trigger que ao adicionar um usuário, você verifica se esse usuário possui algum registro na tabela de `PERMISAO`, se não tiver ele insere uma permisão default, se tiver ele ignora.

Comment: Sim.. o problema não é com os novos usuários, mas sim com os usuários que já existem.. para os novos usuários já fiz este tipo de tratamento

Comment: Para os usuarios existentes você terá que fazer um script de tratamento.
Você pode fazer uma consulta fazendo o JOIN

`select USUARIO.USU_CODIGO, USU_NOME, GRU_CODIGO from USUARIO
left join USUGRUPO
ON USUARIO.USU_CODIGO = USUGRUPO.USU_CODIGO
WHERE GRU_CODIGO IS NULL`

O resultado da pesquisa acima irá me trazer todos os usuarios que não estão na tabela `USUGRUPO`, sendo assim pego esses usuarios e faço um insert com o valor default

Comment: Adaptei esta solução provisória do `left join`.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um id fictício e fazer o seguinte:

```
SELECT (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474) AS id;
```

Funciona com [**PostgreSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/queries-overview.html), [**SQL Server**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx) e[**MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html). Também com [**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause).

Alternativa com `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = 9823474
UNION  ALL
SELECT NULL -- FROM DUAL  -- apenas para Oracle
LIMIT 1;
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found